# How I can overlap my menu in my header picture

Tags: menus, headers

How I can overlap my menu in my header picture. I want the menu can be seen on the header picture. This is the example like I want.

Thank you.

[image]

Example :
[image]

Comment: You can use *position:absolute* css property for overlap menu.

Comment: any possibility of getting its url?

Comment: i think you are using elementor. For this just use global header with condition to all pages so it applies to all pages. and use margin bottom property with negative value of header. Also keep the header background transparent

Answer (score 0):

I just did this on one of my sites today. This is what i have done on css.

```
header.header-class
{
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
div.main-content-className{
margin-top:-75px;
}
```

here change header-class and main-content-className with your theme class name and if necessary make it more margin on top until it will be on top.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Theme builder, go to the header, select the section, position absolute :-)